# requestPinAppWidget with arguments

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using:

```
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("id", item.id)
    appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(provider, bundle, pendingIntent)
```

To pin widget.
I want to pass bundle with argument (some id)

But when configuration activity is launched, the bundle is empty

```
intent?.extras?.getString("id")
```

How to make it work?

Comment: no, I'm managing the id's in shared preference instead

Comment: In what sense? I have a similar problem to yours, but I'm not finding a solution.

Comment: I also tried to use onReceive, but the bundle only contains id:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76209955/android-java-take-value-of-bundle-of-requestpinappwidget

Comment: in onRecieve I save to shared preference the widget id and the associated object id, then in configuration activity I get the object id by the widget id AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, maybe I will able to add some code later

Comment: But every time you add a widget, those preferences are not seen by other widgets or yes?

Comment: what do you mean by other widgets?

Comment: Same widget, but another instance, which may have a different reference text for which it can fetch the data, would be a different url from where it fetches the data.

Comment: every widget has unique id, you can map widget id to url or any object

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing, set:
`SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("urlCode", urlCode);
                editor.apply();`

Comment: I think should be something like editor.putString(widgetId, urlCode), so every widget will have it own url code

Comment: Could you share the code you used?
Or if I share the project link could you take a look at it?

Comment: added some code

Comment: If I share the project with you, do you think you can take a look at it?

Comment: well, lets try, I will try to take a look in the next couple of days

Comment: Inside the project there is a branch in kotlin that I am converting the project to.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find native solution, this way I have manage to solve it.

```
 val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(requireContext())
            val provider = ComponentName(requireContext(), SimpleNotesWidget::class.java)
    
            if (!appWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported) {
                showToast("Pin app widget is not supported")
                return
            }
    
            val pendingIntent = WidgetReceiver.getPendingIntent(requireContext(), listId)
            appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(provider, Bundle(), pendingIntent)
```

Receiver:

```
class WidgetReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    
        companion object {
            const val WIDGET_NAME = "WIDGET_NAME"
    
            fun getPendingIntent(context: Context, checkListId: String): PendingIntent {
                val callbackIntent = Intent(context, WidgetReceiver::class.java)
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putString(WIDGET_NAME, checkListId)
                callbackIntent.putExtras(bundle)
                return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    checkListId.hashCode(),
                    callbackIntent,
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
                    else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            }
        }
    
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (context == null || intent == null) {
                return
            }
    
            val widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1)
            if (widgetId == -1) {
                return
            }
    
            val listId = intent.getStringExtra(WIDGET_NAME)
            val widgetPreferences = WidgetPreferences(context)
            widgetPreferences.setWidgetValues(widgetId, listId!!)
            context.updateWidgets()
        }
    }
```

Configuration Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    widgetId = intent?.extras?.getInt(
        AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
        AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
    ) ?: AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID


    if (widgetId == null) {
        finish()
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(10)
        val listId =
            WidgetPreferences(this).getWidgetListId(widgetId!!)
        if (listId != null && checkWidgetPinned(listId)) {
            configureWidget(widgetId!!, listId)
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                getString(R.string.widget_pinned),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            finish()
        }
    }
}

private fun configureWidget(widgetId: Int, checklistId: String) {
        WidgetPreferences(this@WidgetChecklistPickerActivity).apply {
            setWidgetValues(widgetId, checklistId)
        }
        updateWidgets()
        val resultValue = Intent().putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultValue)
        finish()
    }
```