# Android java take value of Bundle of requestPinAppWidget

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent

When the widget is inserted via `requestPinAppWidget` and the user accepts I have to make the widget retrieve the information that is inside the intent Bundle, and then save this information for the single widget instance.

I've tried various ways to also use `onReceive` but I can't get the data.

Can you give me a hand?

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                String url = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager = getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);
                    if (mAppWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {
                        ComponentName myProvider = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, MyWidget.class);

                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("url", url);

                        Log.d("MainActivity", url);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", b.toString());

                        Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyWidget.class);
                        PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
                                pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

                        mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, b, successCallback);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package com.myapp.test;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    String values = "MyWidget";

    void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_design);

        Log.d("MyWidget3", values);

        //set the value in the textview
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.text, values);

        //update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        //reschedule the widget refresh
        AlarmHandler alarmHandler = new AlarmHandler(context);
        alarmHandler.cancelAlarmManager();
        alarmHandler.setAlarmManager();

        Log.d("WIDGET", "Widget updated!");
    }

/*@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {
            String url = bundle.getString("url", "No value");
            Log.i("TAG", url);
            Log.d("TAG2", bundle.toString());
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId: appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        //stop updating the widget
        AlarmHandler alarmHandler = new AlarmHandler(context);
        alarmHandler.cancelAlarmManager();

        Log.d("WIDGET", "Widget removed!");
    }
}
```